# awk: compute mean values for the data in distinct files

Tags: awk

I am using bash + awk to extract some information from log files located within the directory and save the summary in the separate file.
In the bottom of each log file, there is a table like:

```
mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
   1       -6.961          0          0
   2       -6.797      2.908      4.673
   3       -6.639      27.93      30.19
   4       -6.204      2.949      6.422
   5       -6.111      24.92      28.55
   6       -6.058      2.836      7.608
   7       -5.986      6.448      10.53
   8        -5.95      19.32      23.99
   9       -5.927      27.63      30.04
  10       -5.916      27.17      31.29
  11       -5.895      25.88      30.23
  12       -5.835      26.24      30.36
```

from this I need to focus on the (negative) values located in the second column. Notably I need to take 10 first values from the second column (from -6.961 to -5.916) and compute the mean for it and save the mean value together with the name of the log as one string in new ranking.log
so for 5 processed logs it should be something like:

```
# ranking_${output}.log
log_name1 -X.XXX
log_name2 -X.XXX
log_name3 -X.XXX
log_name4 -X.XXX
log_name5 -X.XXX
```

Where  -X.XXX is the mean value computed for each log for first 10 positions.

Here is my awk code integrated in bash function, which extract the first value (-6.961 in the example table ) from each log (without mean computation).

```
 # take only the first line (lowest dG) from each log
take_the_first_value () {
    awk '$1=="1"{sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME); sub(/\.log/,"",FILENAME); printf("%s: %s\n", FILENAME, $2)}' "${results}"/*.log  > "${results}"/ranking.csv
}
```

May I modify the AWK part to add the computing of the MEAN values instead of taking always the value located in the first line of the table?

Comment: Are there always 10 or more target rows (where $2 is negative) in that table? You have multiple answers that would fail if less than 10 lines were present or if an input file was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v num=10 'BEGINFILE{ c=sum=0 }
     $1~/^[0-9]+$/ && NF==4{
       c++; sum=sum+$2;
       if(c==num){
         sub(/.*\//, "", FILENAME);
         print FILENAME, sum/num
       }
     }' "${results}"/*.log  >> "${results}"/ranking.csv
```

I used `$1~/^[0-9]+$/ && NF==4` to identify the correct lines.

Comment: thank you! in fact it did the computing only for 1 log file while I need to apply it on the many logs located in the same directory, please see my example in the first post where AWK applied on the all logs located in the same filder "${results}"/*.log  > "${results}"/ranking.csv

Comment: @HotJAMS: Okay, I've updated my answer.

Comment: it works! just one question, is it possible to substitute path of each log in the output? it looks now like /Users/jame/Documents/tutorials/dolce_docking/results/name_X7V_rep1.log -8.0069 and I need like simple name_X7V_rep1 -8.0069, what was done before using {sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME); sub(/\.log/,"",FILENAME);

Comment: @HotJAMS: Okay, I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you!! just one question, If I need take into account for instance the five first lines, would it be fine just use if(c==5){print FILENAME, sum/5} ? Where is it specified that I computing mean using FIRST n lines ?

Comment: @HotJAMS: Yes, there are the two right places. I have now swapped out the two places in my answer into a single variable (`num=10`).

Comment: many thanks! just last question: is it possible to use in the last past printf("%s: %s\n", FILENAME, sum/num) instead of print FILENAME, sum/num. e.g. to introduce ":" separator between the both?

Comment: @HotJAMS: Yes, or use `print FILENAME ":", sum/num`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    ($2+0) < 0 {
        sum += $2
        if ( ++cnt == 10 ) {
            nextfile
        }
    }
    ENDFILE {
        print FILENAME, (cnt ? sum/cnt : 0)
        cnt = sum = 0
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
file -6.2549
```

Note that the above will work even if your input files have fewer than 10 lines at the end, including empty files.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin yes they should. I had that in a previous iteration but broke it with an update. Fixed again no, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the averages. The pattern used to find the first value is the line `^---+---` followed by a `[:digit:]` in the first field of the next line. For each log file do

```
$ awk '$1~/[[:digit:]]/ && set==1{ x+=$2; i++;
    gsub(/\/*.*\//,"", FILENAME);               
    if(i==10){ set=0; print FILENAME, x/i; i=0; x=0 } } 
    /^\-+\+\-+/{ set=1 }' "${results}"/*.log > "${results}"/ranking.csv
```

Comment: it does computing but only on one log, while I need to apply the AWK part of any number of the logs and save everything in one log, like indicated in my example AWK code;  awk '$1=="1"{sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME); sub(/\.log/,"",FILENAME); printf("%s: %s\n", FILENAME, $2)}' "${results}"/*.log  > "${results}"/ranking.csv

Comment: @HotJAMS I changed it. Should work for all log files now.